# Delete all records except the max value of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Weight INT NULL,
    Batch INT NULL,
    t_stamp DATETIME NULL
);
```

Let's pretend it was filled with values:

```
INSERT INTO BatchDataWillieNelson (WT401_Raw, Batch_Done_Signal,
                                   Batch_Number, t_stamp)
VALUES (31, 3994, 2, '2023-12-05 06:19:58.990'),
       (32, 4052, 2, '2023-12-05 06:37:24.883'),
       (33, 4000, 5, '2023-12-05 08:44:09.780'),
       (34, 4058, 5, '2023-12-05 08:58:59.683'),
       (35, 4032, 8, '2023-12-05 11:18:11.727'),
       (36, 3983, 11, '2023-12-05 13:20:35.167'),
       (37, 4013, 11, '2023-12-05 13:33:54.877'),
       (38, 3993, 14, '2023-12-05 15:29:50.060'),
       (39, 3470, 14, '2023-12-05 15:48:51.053'),
       (40, 3996, 14, '2023-12-05 17:20:09.893'),
       (41, 3348, 14, '2023-12-05 17:39:22.477'),
       (42, 3993, 2, '2023-12-05 19:48:42.117'),
       (43, 4054, 2, '2023-12-05 20:09:12.217'),
       (44, 3991, 23, '2023-12-05 22:55:45.020'),
       (45, 4065, 23, '2023-12-05 23:16:12.077'),
       (46, 3993, 26, '2023-12-06 02:56:29.713'),
       (47, 4033, 26, '2023-12-06 03:12:24.483'),
       (48, 3982, 26, '2023-12-06 06:06:45.720'),
       (49, 4075, 26, '2023-12-06 06:35:05.197'),
       (50, 3994, 2, '2023-12-06 08:02:58.887'),
       (51, 3029, 2, '2023-12-06 08:28:21.260'),
       (52, 3982, 2, '2023-12-06 09:49:23.497'),
       (53, 4038, 7, '2023-12-06 10:12:41.707')
```

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table that has extra records that were written into it by mistake. I need to remove these.

I need to evaluate the `Weight` column for the max value based on grouping of `Batch_Number`. The same `Batch_Number` can be used multiple times. So, without ordering the table, I was trying to look for the change in `Batch_Number` and treat those rows as a group to evaluate without having to cursor through every record.

Expected results:

| Id | Weight | Batch | t_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 4052 | 2 | '2023-12-05 06:37:24.883' |
| 34 | 4058 | 5 | '2023-12-05 08:58:59.683' |
| 35 | 4032 | 8 | '2023-12-05 11:18:11.727' |
| 37 | 4013 | 11 | '2023-12-05 13:33:54.877' |
| 40 | 3996 | 14 | '2023-12-05 17:20:09.893' |
| 43 | 4054 | 2 | '2023-12-05 20:09:12.217' |
| 49 | 4075 | 26 | '2023-12-06 06:35:05.197' |
| 50 | 3994 | 2 | '2023-12-06 08:02:58.887' |
| 53 | 4038 | 7 | '2023-12-06 10:12:41.707' |

Ok, sorry for the confusion in what I am asking.  Look at the Batch "2"s.  There are 3 sets of them.  I don't want all three of them grouped together.  They each have to be considered their own groups since they are separated by other batch numbers.

| Id | Weight | Batch | t_stamp | expect Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | 3994 | 2 | '2023-12-05 06:19:58.990' | grp 1 - Remove |
| 32 | 4052 | 2 | '2023-12-05 06:37:24.883' | grp 1 - Keep |
| 33 | 4000 | 5 | '2023-12-05 08:44:09.780' | grp 2 - Remove |
| 34 | 4058 | 5 | '2023-12-05 08:58:59.683' | grp 2 - Keep |
| 35 | 4032 | 8 | '2023-12-05 11:18:11.727' | grp 3 - Keep |
| 36 | 3983 | 11 | '2023-12-05 13:20:35.167' | grp 4 - Remove |
| 37 | 4013 | 11 | '2023-12-05 13:33:54.877' | grp 4 - Keep |
| 38 | 3993 | 14 | '2023-12-05 15:29:50.060' | grp 5 - Remove |
| 39 | 3470 | 14 | '2023-12-05 15:48:51.053' | grp 5 - Remove |
| 40 | 3996 | 14 | '2023-12-05 17:20:09.893' | grp 5 - Keep |
| 41 | 3348 | 14 | '2023-12-05 17:39:22.477' | grp 5 - Remove |
| 42 | 3993 | 2 | '2023-12-05 19:48:42.117' | grp 6 - Remove |
| 43 | 4054 | 2 | '2023-12-05 20:09:12.217' | grp 6 - Keep |
| 44 | 3991 | 23 | '2023-12-05 22:55:45.020' | grp 7 - Remove |
| 45 | 4065 | 23 | '2023-12-05 23:16:12.077' | grp 7 - Keep |
| 46 | 3993 | 26 | '2023-12-06 02:56:29.713' | grp 8 - Remove |
| 47 | 4033 | 26 | '2023-12-06 03:12:24.483' | grp 8 - Remove |
| 48 | 3982 | 26 | '2023-12-06 06:06:45.720' | grp 8 - Remove |
| 49 | 4075 | 26 | '2023-12-06 06:35:05.197' | grp 8 - Keep |
| 50 | 3994 | 2 | '2023-12-06 08:02:58.887' | grp 9 - Keep |
| 51 | 3029 | 2 | '2023-12-06 08:28:21.260' | grp 9 - Remove |
| 52 | 3982 | 2 | '2023-12-06 09:49:23.497' | grp 9 - Remove |
| 53 | 4038 | 7 | '2023-12-06 10:12:41.707' | grp 10 - Keep |

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used. Could do a TOP 1 for each batch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Are you sure there's no possibility of ties? Presumably you'd want to keep the later timestamp?

Comment: Sorry the other critical piece of this is that I have to use SQL Server 2008

Comment: @shawnt00 you are right there could be the possibility of a tie for which i would want to  keep the later record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports operating directly on a table expression, such as SQL Server, the following is another simple approach:

```
delete from d
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by batch order by weight desc) rn
    from t
)d
where rn > 1;
```

See [Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bMh2bOOo)

Comment: I think, this is best method. Works with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: A *very* pedantic aside, you don't need the "from" part in the `delete from d`

Comment: Yes I know, but I always think it adds clarity so tend to use it; ymmv but without 'from' it can read as deleting the entire object so I like to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH MaxWeightPerBatch AS (
    SELECT Batch_Number, MAX(Weight) AS MaxWeight
    FROM tblTest
    GROUP BY Batch_Number
)
DELETE FROM tblTest
WHERE (Batch_Number, Weight) NOT IN (
    SELECT Batch_Number, MaxWeight
    FROM MaxWeightPerBatch
);
```

Find the maximum Weight for each Batch_Number group, and then DELETE the rows from tblTest that do not have the maximum Weight within their respective Batch_Number groups.

Comment: This is a good idea. But it requires a DBMS that accepts both a `WITH` clause for a `DELETE` and an `IN` clause on tuples. Some DBMS do, others don't.

Comment: Batch numbers are not unique. They can be repeated. I could have 3 groups of Batch Number "3" for example.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all rows for which exists another row with the same batch number and a higher weight/signal.

```
delete from batchdatawillienelson
where exists
(
  select null
  from batchdatawillienelson other
  where other.batch_number = batchdatawillienelson.batch_number
  and other.batch_done_signal > batchdatawillienelson.batch_done_signal
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the canonical method.

Comment: Batch numbers are not unique.  They can be repeated.  I could have 3 groups of Batch Number "3" for example.

Comment: Well, of course batch numbers are not unique. This is what it's all about. You can have several rows for one batch number and want to delete all except for the one with the greatest signal. This is what we address in our three answers. Our do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes I mean something else.  I will add the example in original question

Comment: @godesteem: This new requirement has changed the task completely. Thus you have three answers that solved the originally described problem perfectly, but don't match the new request. Don't make such significant changes. Please roll back the changes you made to the request, accept one of the answers (it doesn't matter which) and write a new request for the altered task. Thus the two separate requests are consistent and helpful for future readers. Your new task involves a "gaps and islands" problem, by the way. Maybe you want to figure this out alone, otherwise write the separate request.